# Hierarchical kendo grid pdf export

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, hierarchical-data, export-to-pdf

I am trying to `export` `hierarchical kendo grid` in `PDF`. But when I try to `export PDF` it gives only the master rows are being exported, it does not include hierarchy data in the export.

I have done `excel export` using [detail-grid-export-to-excel](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/excel/detail-grid-export). But I cant find any thing for `PDF export with hierarchical data`.

I have used following code:-

```
     var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     toolbar: ["excel","pdf"], 
     pdf: {
              allPages: true,
              fileName: fileName+".pdf",
              proxyURL: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
          }
```

Thank you

Comment: Although this post was asked before these others, this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37791939/731081) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111481/731081)