# How to use export to excel in Hierarchical Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a Kendo Hierarchical grid which i have developed using Kendo MVC 2016.2.504.545 version.
This grid has a state which gets drilled down to city and the city which gets drilled down to the persons Address.
Now i want to perform a export to excel functionality in this grid.
I call individual actions to populate results for the city, state and the address data in the kendo grid.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got some help with the telerik people and was able to achieve the functionality as required, you can find the following project here

[detail-grid-excel-export](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/detail-grid-excel-export)

[detail-grid-excel-export-all-pages-all-details](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/detail-grid-excel-export-all-pages-all-details)

​I hope this information helps.